# numpy selecting every other n entries

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Does anyone perhaps know a clever way to select every other group of n entries in a numpy array? For example here Id like to select all "unique" entries 0,1,4,5,8,9 etc. (n=2) without resorting to a sort:

```
[[ 0  2]
 [ 1  3]
 [ 2  0]
 [ 3  1]
 [ 4  6]
 [ 5  7]
 [ 6  4]
 [ 7  5]
 [ 8 10]
 [ 9 11]
 [10  8]
 [11  9]
 [12 14]
 [13 15]
 [14 12]
 [15 13]]
```

Building an index array before hand is an option but I was wondering if anyone had a better idea!

Comment: Could you give a sample desired output?

Comment: It is as unutbu provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could reshape the array to add an extra dimension of length 2:

```
In [10]: x.reshape(-1,2,2)
Out[10]: 
array([[[ 0,  2],
        [ 1,  3]],

       [[ 2,  0],
        [ 3,  1]],

       [[ 4,  6],
        [ 5,  7]],

       [[ 6,  4],
        [ 7,  5]],

       [[ 8, 10],
        [ 9, 11]],

       [[10,  8],
        [11,  9]],

       [[12, 14],
        [13, 15]],

       [[14, 12],
        [15, 13]]])
```

Then select every other item along the first axis:

```
In [11]: x.reshape(-1,2,2)[::2]
Out[11]: 
array([[[ 0,  2],
        [ 1,  3]],

       [[ 4,  6],
        [ 5,  7]],

       [[ 8, 10],
        [ 9, 11]],

       [[12, 14],
        [13, 15]]])
```

and finally reshape it back to a 2D array:

```
In [12]: x.reshape(-1,2,2)[::2].reshape(-1,2)
Out[12]: 
array([[ 0,  2],
       [ 1,  3],
       [ 4,  6],
       [ 5,  7],
       [ 8, 10],
       [ 9, 11],
       [12, 14],
       [13, 15]])
```

Comment: This works beautifully! Hadnt expect the reshape to be such a useful tool :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let l = your original list, then what you want is:

```
[x for i, x in enumerate(l) if (i // 2) % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: That looks really nice. List comprehension looks really powerful. However seeing that I`m using numpy I get:  [array([0, 4]),
 array([1, 5]), etc. Any ideas? I could resort to using normal arrays instead but Id rather not if possible.

Comment: Try converting back to np.array at the end: array([x for i, x in enumerate(l) if (i // 2) % 2 == 0])